# Reveal.js Detecting browser support

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

Is there any way to identify the browser supports Reveal.js or not so that for non supported browser users I can provide a meaningful message?

I mean some solution like what impress.js provides (special div is displayed if browser is not supported and automatically hidden if there browser support).

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying "identify the browser supports Reveal.js". This is a library and not a feature or an API of JavaScript language. Do you want to check if the web page has loaded the reveal.js script file?

Comment: Reveal.js (internally css3 etc) is supported by mordern browsers.If a user is using an old browser(eg i.e 6) the reveal.js feature will not work.

Comment: Read the documentation https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/wiki/Browser-Support

Comment: Thanks for the link , I had refered this before. Unfortunately the official documentation doesn't clearly mention about browser versions other than I.E . For eg I am using chrome 10.0.648.205 which is not supported by Reveal.js but as per the documentation Chrome supports reveal.js . In such cases I cannot assume browser support just by the browser name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what CSS3 features the library uses.

If you know that, you can use a feature detection library like [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css) to check if they are indeed supported by the browser in question.

You can read this article

http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/
**Update:**

According to https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/wiki/Browser-Support, the library supports all browsers starting from IE8, though with limited capabilities.

Comment: My question is there any easier way provided by Reveal.js for browser support detection.Your suggested way is the very last option that I should write my own browser support detection code for the css3 features used by Reveal.js.

Comment: Libraries usually tend to fallback to earlier versions of browsers. So, it can have a rich set of capabilities for modern browsers and it can fallback to older browsers supporting a limited set of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

reveal.js includes head.js which, in theory, can identify browsers and "features" such as touch and screen size. The problem is that the version included is old and can't. Upload it and you should be able to do what you want.